# SCSS and ":host([active])"

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, polymer, web-component

I need such construction in scss:

```
:host {
    background: #fff;

    &([active]) {
        background: #000;
    }
}
```

meaning output like:

```
:host {
    background: #fff;
}
:host([active]) {
    background: #000;
}
```

But I can't get it working any way I've tried. Is there any way to escape parentheses I don't know or something not overcomplicated?

Just inserting piece of raw css like `code` in CoffeeScript would be great, but I do not see anything like this in documentation.

Comment: Pseudo-classes that are available in both functional and non-functional variants are new to Selectors 4. The functional notation is a special part of selector syntax and does not constitute a valid identifier by itself, which is the reason why your SCSS doesn't work. I wouldn't be surprised if your favorite preprocessor doesn't support this yet.

Comment: You're right, but I hope for some workaround except css usage. In CoffeeScript it is possible to use plain JavaScript.

Comment: Is there a *valid* CSS pseudo selector that's comparable to this?  I can't think of one (eg. `:lang` is not a valid selector, you have to specify the language like `:lang(en)`).

Comment: @cimmanon, :host() is valid and used with Web Components (yes, It's future, but I want to use it today).
There are `:nth-child()` and family, they all works fine with scss.

Comment: `:nth-child()` is just like `:lang()`: you must supply a value, you can't just use `:nth-child` or `:lang`.  The `:first-child`/`:last-child` set of pseudo selectors don't take values.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this shadow DOM selectors in the scss files you cant use `:host(<selector>)` nested right now.
A workaround is to repeat :host for each selector you want to use.

**SCSS**:

```
:host {
    background: #fff;
}
:host([active]) {
    background: #000;
}
```

**CSS (the same)**:

```
:host {
  background: #fff;
}

:host([active]) {
  background: #000;
}
```

You could try it here: http://sassmeister.com/

Comment: `:host([active])` is perfectly valid for Shadow DOM and regular CSS, while `:host:active` is not. It works only because you're using Polymer which does very straightforward approximation of Shadow DOM. It wont work under native Shadow DOM.

Comment: I thought what you wanted is use the `:active` selector. I assume you are trying to get all the elements with an `active` attribute. Then the only way to do that is without nesting in scss.

Comment: Yes, I already use this syntax for many months, I just wanter to use nesting in SCSS. But this is not possible yet.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly sass still doesn't support this.
I made an additional workaround to support nested state selectors on :host

Assuming you also use gulp-sass to compile your sass to css you can do the following:

> npm install gulp-replace

Next add the following to the top of the gulp script that compiles your sass:

```
var replace = require('gulp-replace');
```

And add the following to your sass compile pipe:

```
.pipe(replace(':host:hover', ':host(:hover)'))
```

---

Now you can use the following construct in your sass:

### Sass

```
:host {
    &:hover {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

The replace function will change your css to look like this:

### CSS

```
:host(:hover) {
  color: red;
}
```

Your gulp script should look something like this:

### Gulp

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('./src/sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            outputStyle: 'expanded',
            precision: 10,
        }))
        .pipe(replace(':host:hover', ':host(:hover)'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'));
});
```

You can add more states by expanding the replace part of your gulp script.

Answer (score -1):

You can write such a helper

```css
@use 'sass:selector';

@function str-replace($string, $search, $replace: '') {
    $index: str-index($string, $search);

    @if $index {
        @return str-slice($string, 1, $index - 1)+$replace +str-replace(str-slice($string, $index + str-length($search)), $search, $replace);
    }

    @return $string;
}

@mixin hover {
    @media (hover: hover) {
        $selectors: ();

        @each $selector in selector.parse(&) {
            $hoverselector: unquote(#{$selector});

            @if (length($selector)==1 and str-index($hoverselector, ':host')) {
                @if ($hoverselector ==':host') {
                    $hoverselector: ':host(:hover)'
                }

                @else {
                    $hoverselector: str-replace($hoverselector, ':host(', ':host(:hover');
                }
            }

            @else {
                $hoverselector: $hoverselector +':hover'
            }

            $selectors: append($selectors, $hoverselector, comma);
        }

        @at-root #{$selectors} {
            cursor: pointer;

            @content;
        }
    }
}


/* usage */

@use 'helpers.scss';

:host,
:host button,
:host([disabled]) {
    @include helpers.hover {
        color: red;
    }
}

.my-class button {
    @include helpers.hover {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

With result

```css
@media (hover: hover) {
  :host(:hover), :host button:hover, :host(:hover[disabled]) {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: red;
  }
}

@media (hover: hover) {
  .my-class button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: red;
  }
}
```