# How to use SASS to factor out :host in CSS?

Tags: css, sass, web-component

I have this sass code

```
:host { 
    padding:10px;
}
:host(.headroom) {
    position: fixed;
}
```

but how can I turn it into like

```
:host { 
    padding:10px;
    &(.headroom) {
        position: fixed;
    }
}
```

SASS complains with a syntax error if I do that.

Comment: The Sass Ampersand - https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/

Comment: I did try the & in my example code, but it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SCSS and ":host(\[active\])"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25825541/scss-and-hostactive)

Answer (score 1):

`(.headroom)` is not a valid selector on its own. I would either go with the unnested variant or make use of the [`@at-root`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_at-root__at-root) directive:

```
:host { 
    padding:10px;

    @at-root #{&}(.headroom) {
      position: fixed;
    }
}
```

which outputs:

```
:host {
  padding: 10px;
}
:host(.headroom) {
  position: fixed;
}
```